# Creating Time Series columns in R from Long to Wide format considering Date Range

Tags: r, time-series, reshape, wide-column-store

To start with I've successfully converted my data from long to wide format.
The data is as below.

```
+======+==========+======+======+
| Name |   Date   | Val1 | Val2 |
+======+==========+======+======+
| A    | 1/1/2018 |    1 |    2 |
+------+----------+------+------+
| B    | 1/1/2018 |    2 |    3 |
+------+----------+------+------+
| C    | 1/1/2018 |    3 |    4 |
+------+----------+------+------+
| D    | 1/4/2018 |    4 |    5 |
+------+----------+------+------+
| A    | 1/4/2018 |    5 |    6 |
+------+----------+------+------+
| B    | 1/4/2018 |    6 |    7 |
+------+----------+------+------+
| C    | 1/4/2018 |    7 |    8 |
+------+----------+------+------+
```

To convert the above table from long to wide format I've used following lines of code:

```
test_wide <- reshape(test_data, idvar = 'Name', timevar = 'Date', direction = "wide" )
```

The result from the above code is as follows:

```
+======+===============+===============+===============+===============+
| Name | Val1.1/1/2018 | Val2.1/1/2018 | Val1.1/4/2018 | Val2.1/4/2018 |
+======+===============+===============+===============+===============+
| A    | 1             | 2             |             5 |             6 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| B    | 2             | 3             |             6 |             7 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| C    | 3             | 4             |             7 |             8 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| D    | NA            | NA            |             4 |             5 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

The issue that I am facing is that I need R to consider `Date` column in date format. The date column ranges from `1/1/2018` to `1/4/2018` since there is no value in date `1/2/2018` and `1/3/2018`I won't see any columns as `Val1.1/2/2018`, `Val2.1/3/2018`, `Val3.1/2/2018` and `Val3.1/3/2018`.

I want to convert into wide format such that I can get columns for date `1/2/2018` and `1/3/2018`, eventhough those columns would contain only NULLS.

Reason for doing it is that I need to use the data as time series.

Edit:

Initial data in copy and pasted:

```
Name Date Val1 Val2
A 1/1/2018 1 2
B  1/1/2018 2 3
C 1/1/2018 3 4
D 1/4/2018 4 5
A 1/4/2018 5 6
B  1/4/2018 6 7
C 1/4/2018 7 8
", header=TRUE)
```

Converted data copy and pasted:

```
Name,Val1.1/1/2018,Val2.1/1/2018,Val1.1/4/2018,Val2.1/4/2018
A,1,2,5,6
B,2,3,6,7
C,3,4,7,8
D,NA,NA,4,5
```

dput(test_data) results:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B ", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1/1/2018", "1/4/2018"), class = "factor"), 
    Val1 = 1:7, Val2 = 2:8), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Please provide data in copy-paste format or using `dput`. Meanwhile, see `tidyr::complete`

Comment: As @A.Suliman suggested, you should use the output of `dput` to put into the post, it is much easier for folks to help you that way. For example `dput(test_data)`.

Comment: @steveb and @A.Suliman I've added `dput(test_data)` result in `Edit` section. I hope that's what you require.

Comment: Could someone please suggest a way that I should look up to replicate the same in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #complete
library(data.table) #dcast and setDT
df %>% mutate(Date=as.Date(Date,'%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
       complete(Name, nesting(Date=full_seq(Date,1))) %>%
       setDT(.) %>% dcast(Name ~ Date, value.var=c('Val2','Val1'))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` option

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date=mdy(Date)) %>% 
  #Or you can do as.Date(Date,'%m/%d/%Y') to avoid loading `lubridate`
  complete(Name, Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), 1)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -Name, -Date) %>%
  unite(Date, key, Date, sep = ".") %>%
  spread(Date, value)
```